# Return exception in switch statement and then throw the called method

Tags: java, exception, switch-statement, throw

I have two methods

```
private String handleResponse(HttpResponse httpResponse){
    if (response.getStatusCode() / 100 == 2) {
        return response.getEntity().toString()
    } else {
        throw handleException(response.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

```
private RuntimeException handleException(int errorStatusCode){
    switch(errorStatusCode) {
        case 400:
            return new RuntimeException("Invalid request");
        case 401:
            return new RuntimeException("User not authorized");
        default:
            return new RuntimeException("Unkown exception");
    }
}
```

Everything works as expected, but is this approach correct? I mean to return new RuntimeException from a switch in a method and then throw the whole method ? Something tells me that it is not and I would like to know why and how can i improve it..

Comment: Why don't you make your `handleException` throw the exception immediately instead of returning it?

Comment: Plus, as your code is currently working and you are just seeking advice, I believe this question is more for the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange forum.

Comment: Then return the message from the switch and throw the exception at the callsight.

Comment: @AnisR. I would like to but then Idea is complaining that also else branch should return some statement

Comment: `response.getStatusCode() / 100 == 2` Dude, really? Is `response.getStatusCode() == 200` for the weak?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Reason of that is API which i'm calling can return as a successful response 200, 201, 204. But i'm open to any suggestions

Comment: @MarkyMark I mean `201`, `204` are way more descriptive than `1`, `4`. Don't bring unnecessary complexity.

Comment: You know what's even more readable? Writing a proper, typeseafe, [OO API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html#is2xxSuccessful--). This is Java, not C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get rid of `response.getStatusCode() / 100 == 2`. Write `response.getStatusCode() == 200` or `response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK` instead.
2. Remove the `else` branch and `throw` after the `if` statement.
3. Rename the method to `getExceptionByStatusCode` or `generateExceptionForStatusCode`. You don't `handleException`, you decide which one to throw.
4. Choose the right return type. Don't use `RuntimeException`. It can be `ResponseStatusException` or any other type appropriate to the HTTP/your domain abstraction.
5. For each case, decide what type you want to return. Again, not `RuntimeException`.

A bit improved version would be

```
private String handleResponse(HttpResponse response) {
    final int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();

    if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        return response.getEntity().toString();
    }

    throw getExceptionByStatusCode(statusCode);
}

private MyDomainHTTPException getExceptionByStatusCode(int statusCode) {
    switch (statusCode) {
        case HttpStatus.SC_NOT_FOUND:
            return new MyDomainHTTPException("...");
        case HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED:
            return new MyDomainHTTPException("...");
        default:
            return new MyDomainHTTPException("...");
    }
}
```

That said, returning an exception in Java doesn't *feel* right.

It works fine but it doesn't seem absolutely correct because of the "special" status of exceptions. It can be justifiable when there is lazy evaluation,  and you will be throwing the exception when you meet a certain condition in the future, or in cases with `Optional.orElseThrow`.

It might be confusing to some people who got used to the `throw new` template and never thought that returning an exception is a compilable option.

In large frameworks (Spring, PrimeFaces - if my memory serves me correctly), I saw exception factories used to compose exceptions based on the given context and rules. They definitely employ exceptions more extensively than we do. So you may ignore my feeling ;)

Comment: I would `return String` and call the method `getErrorMessageByStatusCode()`. It removes the duplication, allows you to throw on creation and generally makes the code more sane.

Comment: @BoristheSpider you may want to return different (more descriptive) types with a different number of params

Answer (score 1):

You can make it a bit shorter and more intuitive in the following way:

```
private String handleResponse(HttpResponse httpResponse){
    if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        return response.getEntity().toString()
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(getErrorMessage(response.getStatusCode());
    }
}

private String getErrorMessage(int errorStatucCode){
    switch(errorStatucCode) {
        case 400:
            return "Invalid request";
        case 401:
            return "User not authorized";
        default:
            return "Unkown exception";
}
```

Comment: I was also thinking of that option, but what if i once need to create RuntimeException with another constructor using Throwable? For example  `throw new RuntimeException(getErrorMessage(response.getStatusCode(), cause);`

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with what you have, but you may find it more natural to immediately throw the exception when it's created:

```
private String handleResponse(HttpResponse httpResponse){
    if (response.getStatusCode() / 100 == 2) {
        return response.getEntity().toString()
    } else {
        throwException(response.getStatusCode());
    }
}

private void throwException(int errorStatusCode){
    switch(errorStatusCode) {
        case 400:
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid request");
        case 401:
            throw new RuntimeException("User not authorized");
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("Unkown exception");
    }
}
```

---

> The API I'm calling can return as a successful response 200, 201, 204. But I'm open to any suggestions.

If you'll accept any 2xx status code, how about:

```
if (response.getStatusCode() >= 200 && response.getStatusCode() <= 299) {
```

Comment: It compiles. All paths are covered thanks to the `default` case.